# How to iterate through an array of arrays and make it return only a handful of elements depending on React state

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, slice

I have an array that contains other arrays:

```
export const ArtifactArray = [
  AccessoriesArtifacts,
  BodyArtifacts,
  CloakArtifacts,
  FeetArtifacts,
  HandsArtifacts,
  HeadArtifacts,
  LeftHandArtifacts,
  MainHandArtifacts,
  NeckArtifacts
]
```

Each of these arrays contain objects:

```
export const BodyArtifacts = [
  WonderArmor,
  BrimstoneBreastplate,
  PetrifiedWoodBreastplate,
  DragonScaleArmor,
  RibCage,
  GreatBasilistScales,
  TitansCuirass,
  CyclopsKingTunic,
];
```

Later on I'm iterating through the array and displaying all of these objects on the screen like this:

```
{ArtifactArray.map((array, index) => (
  <Fragment key={index}>
    {array.map((artifact, index) => (
      <ArtifactsBlock
        key={index}
        src={artifact.pic}
        name={artifact.name}
      />
    ))}
  </Fragment>
))}
```

Everything works as expected.

Then I'm trying to add a pagination to it, and that's where the problem begins. I want to return only 20 objects per page (120 in total). But how do I do that if those arrays don't have the same number of objects in each? If I use array.slice(0, 20), array.slice(20, 40), etc. by the end of some of those arrays it will return 11 or 9 instead. Of course I could get rid of those inner arrays and simply lump all objects into one array, but that's clunky as hell. I'd like to keep it the way it is now.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating your issue when others copy and paste it into their own IDEs, without any other issues. Currently, you have added many objects that are not defined. Please consider to add some of them and remove the rest

Comment: If you're using React you may want to add that tag so this gains more visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [flattening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) your list?

```js
{ArtifactArray.flat().slice(i, i + pageLen).map(artifact, index) => (
  <ArtifactsBlock
    key={index}
    src={artifact.pic}
    name={artifact.name}
  />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the arrays of objects down to one array, and then use the length of that array plus a "limit" of the number of items to show to determine how you're going to slice your data.

Here's a small working example which uses a small dataset (a total of eleven items). The data is flattened and passed into the component. There are two states: one for the page, and one for the limit. Note: here the limit is set to two items per page.

When the component is rendered it calls both the `getPages` and `getArtifacts` functions. They build both a series of page buttons, and an array of artifacts using the information in the page and limit states.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example({ artifacts }) {

  const [ page, setPage ] = useState(0);
  const [ limit, setLimit ] = useState(2);

  // Return a subset of data from the artifacts state based
  // on the page number, and the page limit
  function getArtifacts() {
    return artifacts
      .slice(page * limit, (page * limit) + limit)
      .map(artifact => {
        return (
          <Artifact
            key={artifact.id}
            data={artifact}
          />
        );
      });
  }

  // Update the page state
  function handlePage(e) {
    const { dataset: { page } } = e.target;
    setPage(+page);
  }

  // Create a series of pages based on the number of objects
  // in the artifacts state, and the page limit. Add an active prop
  // to indicate which page button should be highlighted
  function getPages() {

    const arr = [];
    const mod = artifacts.length / limit;
    const pages = mod % limit === 0 ? mod : Math.floor(mod) + 1;

    for (let p = 0; p < pages; p++) {
      arr.push((
        <Page
          key={p}
          number={p}
          active={p === page}
          handlePage={handlePage}
        />)
      );
    }

    return arr;

  }

  // Get the pages and the artifacts
  return (
    <main>
      <h2>Artifacts</h2>
      <section className="pages">
        {getPages()}
      </section>
      <section className="artifacts">
        {getArtifacts()}
      </section>
    </main>
  );

}

// Return an artifact name
function Artifact({ data }) {
  return <section><h4>{data.name}</h4></section>;
}

// Return a page
function Page({ number, active, handlePage }) {
  
  const cn = ['page', active && 'active'].join(' ');
  
  return (
    <button
      className={cn}
      data-page={number}
      type="button"
      onClick={handlePage}
    >{number + 1}
    </button>
  );

}

const bodyArtifacts=[{id:"ba1",name:"WonderArmor"},{id:"ba2",name:"BrimstoneBreastplate"},{id:"ba3",name:"PetrifiedWoodBreastplate"},{id:"ba4",name:"DragonScaleArmor"},{id:"ba5",name:"GreatBasilistScales"},{id:"ba6",name:"TitansCuirass"},{id:"ba7",name:"CyclopsKingTunic"}];
const cloakArtifacts=[{id:"ca1",name:"RedCloak"},{id:"ca2",name:"BlueCloak"},{id:"ca3",name:"PinkCloak"},{id:"ca4",name:"GoldCloak"}];
const artifacts=[bodyArtifacts,cloakArtifacts];

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);

// Pass in the flattened data
root.render(<Example artifacts={artifacts.flat()} />);
```

```css
.page { width: 30px; aspect-ratio: 1; border-radius: 5px;}
.page:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 0.25rem; }
.page:hover:not(.active) { background-color: #fffff0; cursor: pointer; }
.active { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```